# LDA: Assign more than one topic to a document

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, lda, topic-modeling

I´m new to LDA and doing some experiments with Python + LDA and some sample datasets.
I already got some very interesting results and now I asked myself a question but couldn´t find an answer so far.
Since I worked with customer reviews/ratings of a certain app the documents contain different topics (e.g. one talks about the app performance, price, functionality). So for my understanding I got three topics within one document.

**My question:** Is LDA capable to assign more than one topic to one document?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is specific to machine learning rather than software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You may consider visiting [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is the whole idea of LDA - is searched for topic distribution inside the documents. So it will assign several topics to documents (unless they are too short).